# OpenShift pod certificate installation

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openshift

I have an OpenShift PHP pod running an application and I need to authenticate a user account against an Active Directory server. The LDAP bind is failing with a certificate error

```
LDAP Error (authenticateUser), Cannot bind to LDAP : error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate) - ldap_bind failed
```

It was suggested I need to install the AD servers certificate into the pod. The certificate has now been copied into the Git repository. I thought I may be able to use a Life Cycle Hook to install the certificate into /etc/openldap/certs/

```
rollingParams:
  post:
    execNewPod:
      command:
        - /bin/sh
        - '-c'
        - >-
          /usr/bin/cp
          /opt/app-root/src/certificates/certificate.pem
          /etc/openldap/certs/
      containerName: application
    failurePolicy: Ignore
```

However there is a permissions error - I assume that the deployment is not running as root so the directory is not accessible.

```
/usr/bin/cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/openldap/certs/certificate.pem': Permission denied
```

Is it possible to copy this certificate using the DeploymentConfig or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered installing the CA on the container image itself? you could also include that part of the container startup script and mount the certificate at runtime

Comment: How would you update the container image in OpenShift? With the second part of your suggestion, all I could find was https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ca-certificates-cli which requires root permissions.

Comment: if its an internal ocp image then installing the cluster with the CA is a better alternative, if its a self built image than just add a stage with the ca and the loading part

Comment: I did find the following page which is relevant as the poster is attempting to install a certificate in OpenShift

https://lists.openshift.redhat.com/openshift-archives/users/2018-July/msg00031.html

I managed to create 3 secrets containing the three files in the /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/ directory. They are being injected there but are zero characters in size.

Comment: For fedora based distros, you usually run `update-ca-certificates` after. Maybe further processing of the certs is needed. Also, take into consideration that that's 4 year old post that's might be 
unrelevant at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this. You need to add the ldap.conf and the certificate to ConfigMaps.

```
 oc create configmap configmap_name --from-file=filenam=path and filename
```

Then you need to mount the ConfigMaps:

```
  volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/openldap/ldap.conf
          name: openldap-ad-config-volume
          subPath: ldap.conf
        - mountPath: /etc/openldap/certs/certificate.pem
          name: ad-certificate-volume
          subPath: certificate.pem

  volumes:
    - configMap:
        defaultMode: 292
        name: openldap-ad-config
      name: openldap-ad-config-volume
    - configMap:
        defaultMode: 292
        name: ad-certificate
      name: ad-certificate-volume
```

Property subPath is used so that the rest of the contents of the directory are not excluded as mounting normally mounts the whole of the directory. Property defaultMode is used otherwise the files will be world read/write.